# how to choose color for slidingdrawer

Tags: android, xml, android-handler, android-sliding, android-background

I want to make drawer in xml with backcolor, and when I open the drawer, I see the backcolor, but if I didnt open the drawer I dont see the backcolor.

This is what my xml looks like-

```
<SlidingDrawer

    android:id="@+id/slidingD"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:content="@+id/content"
    android:handle="@+id/handle" 

    android:layout_marginTop="150dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/handle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="^" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cbSlidable"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="CheckBox" />
    </LinearLayout>
</SlidingDrawer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to set background color in you "content" layout.

Try this.

```
<SlidingDrawer

android:id="@+id/slidingD"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:content="@+id/content"
android:handle="@+id/handle" 
android:layout_marginTop="150dp">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/handle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="^" />


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cbSlidable"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CheckBox" />
</LinearLayout></SlidingDrawer>
```

Hope its help